# Losing Alt-Gr characters in a templated list controls

Tags: .net, wpf, unicode

We are writing software which need to input characters from languages such as Polish & Chinese.  These languages use the Alt-Gr key extensively, such as Alt-Gr-OemQuestion for a } in Spanish or Alt-Gr-s for the ß character in Polish.

Issues:

This works fine in normal text-boxes etc.  However if I have a textbox inside a data-template inside a list control the } character in the Spanish case above gets lost because the list-control absorbs the key-stroke because Alt-Gr is actually Left-Ctrl+Right-Alt and in combination with OemQuestion it triggers the equivalent of Ctrl-A and selects all the items in the list-control!

Similar problem for the Alt-Gr-s in Polish where the fundamental Left-Ctrl+Right-Alt-s actually does a Ctrl-s and triggers a save!

We have found a solution by using pinvoke to use the ToUnicode function in the KeyDown event to get the correct character and insert it into the textbox, but this contravenes the permissions for using a Click-Once application running in isolated storage etc (I think, bit rusty on this stuff).

Anyone with any ideas?